# Copy Paste Macro suddenly doesnt work and shows error: That command cannot be used on multiple selections

Tags: vba, excel

The macro copies values from a table into another table. It worked fine until today it started acting up showing this error:

Copy Paste Macro suddenly doesnt work; Shows Error: That command cannot be used on multiple selections.

The macro:

```
Sub Copy_Results()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Relevant_Sales_Results")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Results")
copySheet.Range("Sales_Table").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Cells(2, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I am thankfull for any help...

Comment: Hint: Type that error message in Google and see what do you get ;)

Answer (score 1):

See this microsoft support link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/214080/xl2000-error-message-that-command-cannot-be-used-on-multiple-selections

It's mentioned in this link that having "irregular range" can sometime cause this error. You might want to make sure you're not trying to "*copy nonadjacent cell or range selections*"

Comment: Link Only answers are frowned upon in stackoverflow.

Comment: There is no problem in searching google but then put an answer which doesn't just point to another site. Links can die anytime :) You may want to see [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Sure. Go ahead and edit it. Make it more meaningful and to be fair, I will reverse the downvote :) I am heading to bed but leave a comment and I will look at it when I wake up :)

Comment: Done, make sure to keep commenting my posts if you see there's a way I can make them better! I'm getting started on stackoverflow and I really see this website/community as an opportunity to become a better programmer so the chances you see me around again are pretty high :)